# Matching command line args

Tags: f#, match, argv

Starting out learning F#.  Want to make a simple program that just tells me what it found in the command line args.  I have:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    match argv with
    | []  -> 42
    | _ -> 43
```

But this gives errors.  If I hover over argv I see:

> val argv : string[]

which is what I would have expected (a list of strings).  However the first match expression has an error:

> Error 1   This expression was expected to have type
>       string []     but here has type
>       'a list

Basically I just want to match on an empty argument list (an empty list of strings).  What's the right way to do that?

I should add: I don't just want a solution (though that would be nice).  I also want to understand what the compiler is looking for here that I'm not giving it.

Answer (score 18):

It might be confusing since `[]` literal is used to signify an empty list, but type `string []` is an array of strings rather than a list.

You can pattern match against an array like this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    match argv with
    | [||]  -> 42
    | _ -> 43
```

Like many seemingly inconsistent things in F#, this is a result of its dual heritage.

In OCaml, you'd use `int list` and `int array` for the types, `[1;2;3]` and `[|1;2;3|]` for the values respectively. But in C#/.NET, square brackets as in `int[]` are the way to indicate you're dealing with an array.

Probably in an attempt to be more approachable for the .NET crowd, in type names F# uses `[]` as an alias for `array`, so both forms are usable. It's rather unfortunate that this coincides with the empty list literal, but leaving that 'as is' was another constraint - one of early goals in F# design was to make it compatible with OCaml code, so that porting from that language to F# is as friction-less as possible.

Comment: Yes!  That is confusing!  Seems inconsistent, too,  but thanks!  your solution works

Comment: @user1443098 do not forget to mark answer (just click to green tick) ;)

Comment: @user1443098: Agreed. It is consistent in a sense, but probably not where you expect it to be. I've added some more background to the answer.

Comment: @scrwtp could you also explain what `[||]` means and why it works?

Comment: @supertopi: that's the empty array literal, in the same way `[]` is an empty list. It's how you'd write an array with zero elements, just the opening and closing bracket are left.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement some command-line utility I suggest using a wonderful library https://github.com/JordanMarr/FSharp.SystemCommandLine or https://github.com/cannorin/FSharp.CommandLine is also good.

But if you want to do that by hand, try

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (argv : string list) = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    match argv with
    | []  -> 42
    | _ -> 43
```

or

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    match argv |> List.ofArray with
    | []  -> 42
    | _ -> 43
```